# How to update sqlite table where values on list using python?

Tags: python, sqlite, list

I want to update table on sqlite contained with many rows

```
tablenew  
id  status
a   old
b   ask
c   old
d   old
```

etc...

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

cur.execute("update tablenew set status =? where id = ?", ('new',list))
```

how to do this in python?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `IN` operator:

```
cur.execute("update tablenew set status = ? where id IN ?", ('new', list))
```